# Implementing A/D conversion circuit to a DIY clamp meter

Tags: adc, current-measurement, diy, hall-effect, clamp

I was looking for cheap clamp meter projects and found this one: [DC non invasive current clamp for oscilloscope DIY](http://electronoobs.com/eng_circuitos_tut12_1.php).
After reading about this project, I noticed that it had a BNC output to read values from an oscilloscope, according to the schematic:
[image: DC/AC current clamp circuit]
So I was wondering if it was possible to implement an A/D conversion circuit so I could have a direct measurement from an LCD connected to the circuit. (And if it's possible, how could I implement such a thing).
According to the construction principle, it would be something like this:

[image: Clamp meter construction principle]

Also, if someone has any recommendations to improve the original circuit, it would be greatly appreciated (for example, I know that the OP amp used is not one of the best for the project).

Comment: Just buy a panel meter. That's what they do.

Comment: It might be easier if you use something like a ACS712 where the amplification is built into the chip. There's plenty of examples of feeding this into an Arduino and having the readout on an LCD. or as DK suggests, just buy a panel meter as these are dirt cheap off the interwebs. You would want to remove the 9M resistor and 10pF cap on the output as they are not required in this application.

Comment: Is there any reference you would recommend?